# Wildlfy 26: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown handler key at javax.security.jacc.api

Tags: java, wildfly, ejb-3.0, elytron, jacc

I am trying to upgrade a monolith application from Wildfly 23 to Wildfly 26.

Originally the application used a dummy configuration of "jaspitest" in the `standalone.xml`

**Old Config for security**

```xml
 <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:2.0">
            <security-domains>
                <security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional">
                            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                        </login-module>
                        <login-module code="RealmDirect" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="jboss-web-policy" cache-type="default">
                    <authorization>
                        <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                    </authorization>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="jaspitest" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication-jaspi>
                        <login-module-stack name="dummy">
                            <login-module code="Dummy" flag="optional"/>
                        </login-module-stack>
                        <auth-module code="Dummy"/>
                    </authentication-jaspi>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="jboss-ejb-policy" cache-type="default">
                    <authorization>
                        <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                    </authorization>
                </security-domain>
            </security-domains>
        </subsystem>
```

Under guidance from the Wildfly migration guide - [Migration Guide](https://docs.wildfly.org/23/WildFly_Elytron_Security.html#Migrate_Legacy_Security_to_Elytron_Security)

This is now expressed as such in the new Wildfly 26 config

```xml
<application-security-domains>
     <application-security-domain name="jaspitest" security-domain="ApplicationDomain" enable-jaspi="false">
     </application-security-domain>
</application-security-domains>
```

Full (redacted) config is here - https://pastebin.com/kEM5gN3C

**Jboss-xml**

```xml
<jboss-web>
    <security-domain>jaspitest</security-domain>
    <context-root>/</context-root>
    <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jsf/ProjectStage</res-ref-name>
        <jndi-name>java:/env/jsf/ProjectStage</jndi-name>
    </resource-ref>
</jboss-web>
```

This configuration is working for unsecured pages on the web application, however trying to login using a JSF login page.

It throws this FATAL error:

```
10:04:17,518 FATAL [uk.co.xxxxxxx.exception.CustomExceptionHandler] (default task-5) [id=2820080d-1642-45d2-9de7-b1e527262bc7, ip=172.28.0.1, url=/parents/login/, user=null, params={form=form, form:email:input=bruce.taylor@xxxxxxx.co.uk, form:loginWithPassword=********, form:password:input=********, javax.faces.partial.ajax=true, javax.faces.partial.execute=@all, javax.faces.partial.render=login, javax.faces.source=form:loginWithPassword}]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown handler key
2022-02-10T10:04:17.520512634Z  at javax.security.jacc.api@2.0.0.Final//javax.security.jacc.PolicyContext.getContext(PolicyContext.java:223)
2022-02-10T10:04:17.520519816Z  at org.glassfish.soteria@1.0.1-jbossorg-1//org.glassfish.soteria.authorization.JACC$2.run(JACC.java:151)
2022-02-10T10:04:17.520523921Z  at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
2022-02-10T10:04:17.520527172Z  at org.glassfish.soteria@1.0.1-jbossorg-1//org.glassfish.soteria.authorization.JACC.getFromContext(JACC.java:149)
2022-02-10T10:04:17.520530561Z  at org.glassfish.soteria@1.0.1-jbossorg-1//org.glassfish.soteria.authorization.JACC.getSubject(JACC.java:49)
2022-02-10T10:04:17.520533842Z  at org.glassfish.soteria@1.0.1-jbossorg-1//org.glassfish.soteria.authorization.spi.impl.ReflectionAndJaccCallerDetailsResolver.getCallerPrincipal(ReflectionAndJaccCallerDetailsResolver.java:33)
2022-02-10T10:04:17.520537741Z  at org.glassfish.soteria@1.0.1-jbossorg-1//org.glassfish.soteria.SecurityContextImpl.getCallerPrincipal(SecurityContextImpl.java:55)
2022-02-10T10:04:17.520549561Z  at deployment.xxxxxxx.war//uk.co.xxxxxxx.security.Authenticator.authenticate(Authenticator.java:340)
2022-02-10T10:04:17.520553467Z  at deployment.xxxxxxx.war//uk.co.xxxxxxx.security.Authenticator.authenticateWithFacesContext(Authenticator.java:311)
2022-02-10T10:04:17.520557396Z  at deployment.xxxxxxx.war//uk.co.xxxxxxx.security.Authenticator.loginAndRedirect(Authenticator.java:293)
2022-02-10T10:04:17.520561301Z  at deployment.xxxxxxx.war//uk.co.xxxxxxx.security.Authenticator$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.loginAndRedirect(Unknown Source)
2022-02-10T10:04:17.520565505Z  at deployment.xxxxxxx.war//uk.co.xxxxxxx.backing.LoginBacking.loginWithPassword(LoginBacking.java:112)
2022-02-10T10:04:17.520569536Z  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2022-02-10T10:04:17.520574368Z  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2022-02-10T10:04:17.520578603Z  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2022-02-10T10:04:17.520582207Z  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
2022-02-10T10:04:17.520585425Z  at javax.el.api@2.0.0.Final//javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:245)
```

A google search shows this error relating to other Application servers like TomEE etc.

Things I have done:

- Upgraded all Maven dependencies relating to Java EE (EJB, Omnifaces, JSFUtils)
- Disabled JACC (this doesn't throw any errors but I cannot login, it just kicks the user back to the login page after successfull auth)

**Archtecture**

The codebase has :

- AuthenticationMechanism implements HttpAuthenticationMechanism
- Authenticator implements IdentityStore
- AuthenticatedUser (serializable bean with user info in it)

It explodes when calling the injected bean of SecurityContext `getCallerPrinciple()`

[image]

As a non-Java EE person, it would be helpful to understand what is actually going on and get pointed in the direction of how to fix this?

- Is this a Wildfly 26 issue?
- Is this a mis-configuration?
- Is this an issue with Elytron setup?
- Does some code need to be implemented?

I don't understand why I need JACC though, there is no Authorization requirements in the existing monolith.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in cli:

/subsystem=elytron/policy=jacc:add(jacc-policy={})

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the issue for unsecured JSF pages and EJB beans

However Authentication is still broken, I will post a separate question for this.

I believe there is a configuration error meaning its failing to Delegate between EJB and other components.

Answer (score 2):

The setup seems somewhat confused. The `LoginBacking` should not directly call the `IdentityStore`. Instead, a backing bean should call `SecurityContext`. The `SecurityContext` then triggers authentication causing the `HttpAuthenticationMechanism` to be called, which then, if needed, calls the `IdentityStore`.

The Soteria project contains a test that demonstrates this for JSF/Faces:

https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/soteria/tree/master/test/app-mem-customform

The relevant part is:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class LoginBacking {
    
    @Inject
    private SecurityContext securityContext;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 3, max = 15, message="Username must be between 3 and 15 characters")
    private String username;
    
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 5, max = 50, message="Password must be between 5 and 50 characters")
    private String password;
    
    public void login() {
        
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        Credential credential = new UsernamePasswordCredential(username, new Password(password));
        
        AuthenticationStatus status = securityContext.authenticate(
            getRequest(context),
            getResponse(context), 
            withParams()
                .credential(credential));
```

Comment: Thanks 

Yea it seems there is a failure in the configuration and this results in delegation of beans not working